# set line breaks within columns in Beamer (R Markdown)

Tags: latex, markdown, multiple-columns, beamer

I am creating a RMarkdown presentation using Szeged as beamer type. Does anyone know how to set a line break bewtween Text 1 and the option list and the Name: ?

[image]

This is the code:

```
## Session

\scriptsize
:::::::::::::: {.columns totalwidth=\textwidth}
::: {.column width="35%"}
Text 1

- option 1
- option 2
- option 3
- option 4


Name: ABCD ZZZZZZ Y

:::
::: {.column width="40%"}

Text 2

- option 1
- option 2
- option 3
- option 4

Name: ABCD ZZZZZZ Y

:::
::: {.column width="35%"}

Text 3

- option 1
- option 2
- option 3
- option 4

Name: ABCD ZZZZZZ Y

:::
::::::::::::::
```

After the line break, I would like the Name to be aligned with the blue arrow and then the actual name below (ABCD ZZZZZZ Y) with same alignment. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align the text with the blue triangles, you could use further items with empty labels:

```
---
title: |
    | Text

author: |
        | Name
        | email
        |
        
date: date

output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Szeged
    slide_level: 2
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: true

linkcolor: false
---

Text 1

- option 1
- option 2
- option 3
- option 4
\item[] Name:
\item[] ABCD ZZZZZZ Y
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sam. But how to add a line between Text  1 and the option lists and also between option lists and Name ?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues There is already a line break between `Text 1` and the list. Do you maybe mean more vertical space???

Comment: in my case, I don't have a break between Text 1 and option list (please see image in my question).

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues I'm officially confused now. The image in your question shows the  itemisation to start in the line below `Text 1`, so there is certainly a line break, isn't it?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues In any case, if you are looking for additional vertical spacing, try `Text 1\bigskip`

Comment: There is a line break between Text 1 and the option list in my code, but not in my image/output. But this last option \bigskip fixes the issue, thanks a lot Sam!